# rqpd promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?

Tags: r, quantile

I am trying to use the relatively new [rqpd](https://rdrr.io/rforge/rqpd/man/rqpd.html) package developed by Roger Koenker and Stefan Bache in R. However, I encounter this error.

Here is a reproducible code:
`data("LaborSupply") fe.fit <- rqpd(lnwg ~ kids +age+disab|year, data=LaborSupply)`

Error in rqpd(lnwg ~ kids + age + disab | year, data = LaborSupply) :
promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?

Could anybody point me towards my mistake?

I tried doing just one covariate, and using as.factor(year), also specifying lambda=0.5, but I still got the same error. I expect to get a regression summary table at the end.

Comment: You are missing the panel argument, which has no default.
Try `fe.fit <- rqpd(formula = lnwg ~ kids + age + disab|year, panel = panel(), data = LaborSupply)`.
If need be, set costum arguments inside the `panel()` function.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick response. However, I get another error:  Error in if (...length() && any(...names() == "Dimnames")) .Object@Dimnames <- fixupDN(.Object@Dimnames) : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed. I have tried `fe.fit <- rqpd(formula = lnwg ~ kids + age + disab|year, panel = panel(), data = LaborSupply,na.omit=na.omit)` but still same error. Would you be able to further help? :)

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Are you using {Ecdat} to retrieve the LaborSupply data.frame?

In any case, in your new code, change the value of the na.omit to TRUE.
Ie: `rqpd(formula = lnwg ~ kids + age + disab|year, panel = panel(), data = LaborSupply, na.omit = TRUE)`